# How to find a database created in Microsoft Management Studio on my computer?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, ssms

I have created a local database "NotDB" in Microsoft Management Studio, but I dont know how to locate this database on my computer. I need a path to this file, beacause i need create a connection string to this database in my Visual Studio project. Could You tell me how can i get a path to this database ?.

Comment: You don't need its path to create the connection string. You need you instance name.

Comment: To view the default location of where MMS creates the database see:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd206993.aspx#Recommendations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In management studio, you can right click on the database and select options. From the list of options on the left, select files. On the right you will see the physical path and filename of the database.